# On which occasions will c++ initialize variables with zero?

Tags: c++, initialization

Every variable should be properly defined and initialized(assign a value to it) before being used. However under some circumstances, c++ will set variables with a default value of zero. Like the case below.

```
class A{
    ...
    static int val;
    ...};

//int val = 10; //This is the usual definition.
int val;//Definition without assigning a value.
...
A a;  //a class A object
std::cout<<a.val;
```

The result would be zero. Obviously, the compiler did something to initialize variable a.val to zero. I am curious about when will they do this generally?

Comment: I'm not sure but for POD I think it gets initialized to 0, but honestly don't rely on this just initialize it yourself.

Comment: @andre No, do not assume that POD is initialized.

Comment: @andre If you're "not sure" then please do not answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization

> Zero initialization is performed in the following situations:
>
> 1. For every named variable with static or thread-local storage duration, before any other initialization.
> 2. As part of [value-initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization) (*i.e. with an empty pair of parentheses or braces*) sequence for non-class types and for members of value-initialized class types that have no constructors.
> 3. When a character array is initialized with a string literal that is too short, the remainder of the array is zero-initialized.

Comment: The last line is dubious. Character arrays are treated the same as all other arrays. `int a[2] = { 2 }` initializes `a[1]` to zero.

Comment: @MSalters The last line was from `§8.5.2[dcl.init.string]/3` (C++11)

Comment: @MSalters item 3 mentions specifically *initialized with a string literal*, i.e. `"abc"`, not with an array initializer like `{'a', 'b', 'c'}`, so it is indeed a special case for character arrays.