# Zero initialization ignoring constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, initialization

Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20403041/on-which-occasions-will-c-initialize-variables-with-zero/20403169#20403169) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48809894/c-zero-initialization) discussion about zero-initialization, I would like to clarify in which situation these two paragraphs [zero-initialization CPP reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization) occur at the same time:

> 2. As part of value-initialization sequence for non-class types and
>    for members of value-initialized class types that have no
>    **constructors**, including value initialization of elements of aggregates
>    for which no initializers are provided.

From this paragraph I understand that a class member must have **no constructor**.

> If T is an non-union class type, all base classes and non-static data
> members are zero-initialized, and all padding is initialized to zero
> bits. The **constructors**, if any, are ignored.

But from this one I understand that the **constructor** of class members, *if any* (they were supposed not to have), are **ignored**.

Then, in which case can I define a constructor for a class member and still **ignore its constructor**?
I made an experiment with these two classes `A` and `B`, and constructing `A{}` calls `B()` (obviously) because `c=1`. Only `B() = default;` will make `c=0`.

```
class B
{
public:
    B() : c{1} {}
    int c;
};

class A
{
public:
    A() = default;
    B b;
};
```

Is it possible? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is this referring to c++98 standard? In C++98 document zero initialization was always occuring which was incorrect wording.

Comment: Afaik this applies for C++11 and on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Then, in which case can I define a constructor for a class member and still ignore its constructor?

Static storage. A class instance with static storage duration will be zero initialised during the static initialisation phase which ignores constructors if any. The constructor is called later in the dynamic initialisation phase.

> Could you give an example?

Here is an example of a class instance with static storage duration:

```
int main()
{
    static A a;
}
```

Comment: It is explicitly indicating "all base classes and **non-static data members** are zero-initialized". Is the CPP text wrong?

Comment: Could you give an example? I have been trying in different ways without any result

Comment: Sorry I tried it but still `c=1`, which means that `A` is calling `B`'s constructor.

Comment: @Victor Yes. That happens during the dynamic initialisation phase.

Comment: Ok, then there is no practical effect, constructor always rules and rewrites the value. I was afraid that it was overruled. BTW I checked the code instructions and I didn't see any `mov 0` for `c`: https://godbolt.org/clientstate/eyJzZXNzaW9ucyI6W3siaWQiOjEsImxhbmd1YWdlIjoiYysrIiwic291cmNlIjoiY2xhc3MgQlxue1xucHVibGljOlxuICAgIEIoKSA6IGN7MX0ge31cbiAgICBpbnQgYztcbn07XG5cbmNsYXNzIEFcbntcbnB1YmxpYzpcbiAgICBBKCkgPSBkZWZhdWx0O1xuICAgIEIgYjtcbn07XG5cbmludCBtYWluKClcbntcbiAgICBzdGF0aWMgQSBhO1xufVxuIiwiY29tcGlsZXJzIjpbeyJpZCI6ImdzbmFwc2hvdCIsIm9wdGlvbnMiOiItc3RkPWMrKzE3In1dfV19

Comment: @Victor I'm not an expert on this, but it is my understanding that the zero initialisation is handled in practice by the operating system before the execution of the application binary begins.